Jenkins terminates process after job finishes
I have a powershell script that starts a process
$pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
// $pinfo = <necessary_settings>

$p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$p.StartInfo = $pinfo

$p.Start()

I do some stuff with this process, then job ends. When job ends Jenkins terminates this process but i want it to continue to live because next sequential jobs also needs that process. How can i do this?
I searched for a solution and found 2 but could not figure out how to use those exactly

-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true passed this as argument when starting jenkins on a slave node but it didnot accept it as valid option. I am not sure whether i did it correctly though

BUILD_ID=dontKillMe - i have seen some recommendation to use this but i couldn't figure out where to pass this?



It is supposed to work like this:
withEnv(['BUILD_ID=dontKillMe']) {
  powershell '''
    ...
  '''
}

Haven't tried if it actually keeps the process alive, but this is how you pass the environment variable to a script
